# Counting Inner Calls in an unknown Python function

Tags: python, function, count

I'm trying to write a function that can count the number of sub-function calls made by an unknown function. The count function will take an unknown function and its arguments (args, kwargs) as parameters, call the function (parameter) and then return the function return value and the number of function calls made inside it and inside all the sub-called functions recursively. And the call to the function itself is not counted.

In case my words didn't quite make sense, here is an example for illustration:

```
def count_calls(function, *args, **kwargs):
#This is the function that I try to write
pass

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def add_hundred(a):
    return add(a, 100)
```

Intended result when running the function:
`count_calls(add, 8, 12) --- (0, 20)` 0 being the number of times sub function calls happened (because call to the function itself is not counted so it's zero here; 20 being the result of `add(8, 12)`
`count_calls(add_hundred, 5) --- (1, 105)` as `add_hundred` will make 1 sub function call of `add`.

I've done some research but can't find any built-in library or function that can do or help this.

Thanks.

Comment: `sys.settrace()` would be your starting point.

Comment: @jasonharper Oh thanks! Looking into it now.